# Is there a adjective describing something that can be intercalated?

Tags: single-word-requests

I want to say the property that some layered structures can be intercalated by other species. Perhaps something like "intercalable". Thanks.

Comment: [DNA cleavage by intercalatable cobalt](https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlelanding/1996/cc/cc9960001515/unauth#!divAbstract).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume that you refer to the intercalation of 2-D lattices by other ionic species. If so, [Semantic Scholar](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/DNA-cleavage-by-intercalatable-complexes-activated-Bhattacharya-Mandal/bdb18e2882b3f9a76c89e51337d133c345564aa6) shows one example of many where *intercalatable* is used. According to Google's ngram viewer, the word came into use in the 1960s, reached a peak in about 1990 and has declined in usage since. It expresses exactly what you describe.

Comment: Thank you so much! this is what I'm looking for.

Comment: Happiness all round; you are welcome!